# import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.* becomes unused import directive

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, gradle, import

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

is showing up as an unused import directive
the code I have is as follows:
`

```
package com.example.worst_calculator

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

`

for hours I have been having a problem with import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.* returning an unresolved reference error. non of the solutions online seem to apply to my specific problem. I then tried applying the gradle.build module code from an imported project where it works (I also tried importing the gradle.build project code but that was throwing up a ton of errors) and I am left with my current predicament.

the gradle.build code is as follows:
`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
}
```

`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    namespace 'com.example.worst_calculator'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.worst_calculator"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

``

Comment: The kotlinx synthetics stuff is all deptecated.  You should be using View Binding instead.  See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration for how to move to it

Comment: still extension need to work @GabeSechan

Comment: @GabeSechan for this specific project I am supposed to use the synthetics. its how my teacher directed us to complete the program.

Comment: @new_guy91 Here's a lesson in software engineering for you-  requirements can be questioned.  If they don't make sense, they should be questioned.  Talk to your professor about it.  While there are sometimes reasons to not use built in stuff so you learn how it work (for example implementing your own linked list in a data structures class), there's no reason to use obsoleted tools that you're going to need to hack around to get working.

Comment: Are you directed to use Kotlin 1.7.20? Synthetics are officially supposed to stop working in Kotlin 1.8, but the transition from Kotlin 1.7.10 to 1.7.20 seems to have broken it early for a lot of people. I don't know if it's just a coincidence, but the release of 1.7.20 seems to have been around when many people started having trouble getting synthetics to work at all and asking about it on this site, so you could try downgrading to an earlier version of Kotlin.

Comment: @Tenfour04 no I'm not actually, I just updated it in response to the warning. Ill see if using an earlier version works.

Answer (score 0):

This Gradle plugin is Deprecated - 'kotlin-android-extensions'

Step 1: Remove 'Kotlin-android-extensions' from the plugin. In your code remove all imports like 'import kotlinx.android.synthetic.' for access UI.
If your app uses Parcelable you can use 'kotlin-parcelize' instead of 'kotlin-android-extensions'.

Step 2: If your app uses Kotlin synthetics for view binding,
Use this guide to migrate to Jetpack ViewBinding 'https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding'

Add the below code in your build.gradle

```
   buildFeatures {
       viewBinding true
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the import without any issue, so it can be safely removed